# Application caching in applications in offline state now

Tags: caching, web-applications, offline

I considering implementing **application caching** on a .net application. Can I safely assume that all IE (including 9) does NOT support application caching BUT will safely ignore it (graceful degradation)?

Lastly, am I right to say that the real benefit of application caching is reducing conditional request/calls for files as opposed to normal browser caching?